# Why is my custom password reset link deemed invalid?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

My goal is to send my users an email containing a link which takes them directly to the password reset page for their user account specifically, the page where users enter their new password.

Im using the get_password_reset_key function to generate a key which is placed into the custom url, however, when I test it, I get redirected to the password reset page with an invalid key error.

```
$resetpasskey = get_password_reset_key($row[1]);
$reseturl = "http://nameofmysite.co.uk/my-account/lost-password/?key=".$resetpasskey."&login=".$row[1]; 
wp_mail('dean@dean.co.uk','test key',$reseturl);
```

The key does output a value which looks like a valid resetkey which is the standard 20 characters long.

`$Row[1]` being the username of the targeted user.

`$Reseturl` being the password reset url in my email.

Comment: Include more code such as the password reset page that throws your `"invalid key error"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect the reason it is invalid is because you're passing in the incorrect parameter.

If you look at the WordPress code for `get_password_reset_key()`, you'll see that it expects the argument to be a `WP_User` - *not* the username (code comment from the WP code below):

```
/**
 * Creates, stores, then returns a password reset key for user.
 *
 * @since 4.4.0
 *
 * @global wpdb         $wpdb      WordPress database abstraction object.
 * @global PasswordHash $wp_hasher Portable PHP password hashing framework.
 *
 * @param WP_User $user User to retrieve password reset key for.
 *
 * @return string|WP_Error Password reset key on success. WP_Error on error.
 */
function get_password_reset_key( $user ) {
```

So, given the code you've shared, you'd need to modify it along these lines:

```
// I'd recommend changing to use `$row['username']`, but that depends on how you get the data
$user = get_user_by( 'login', $row[1] );
$resetpasskey = get_password_reset_key( $user );
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I just needed to pass the WP_User object instead of me passing the username. Cant believe I missed that! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This is the magic sauce. Thanks for pointing out the difference between arguments!